# Angular 2, subscribe when coordinates are received

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

I'm learning Angular 2. I'm using a LocationService with an Observable that hands me the coordinates after some time. This is my code.

**location.service.ts**

```
public getLocation(): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.create(observer => {
        if(window.navigator && window.navigator.geolocation) {
            window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                (position) => {
                    observer.next(position);
                    observer.complete();
                },
                (error) => observer.error(error)
            );
        } else {
            observer.error('Unsupported Browser');
        }
    });
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.location.getLocation().subscribe((coordinates) => {
        this.lat = coordinates.coords.latitude;
        this.lng = coordinates.coords.longitude;
    });
}
```

> How can I subscribe to the receiving of the coordinates **so I can render a map, add a marker,** .. once I receive them from the first subscribe.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firstly, I would put that method into a service.

So say you have a file called `location.service.ts` with the `export class LocationService` inside this file you'll have the following

```
getLocation(): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.create(observer => {
        if(window.navigator && window.navigator.geolocation) {
            window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                (position) => {
                    observer.next(position);
                    observer.complete();
                },
                (error) => observer.error(error)
            );
        } else {
            observer.error('Unsupported Browser');
        }
    });
}
```

Inside your component you'll do something like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LocationService } from '/shared/location.service.ts';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implments OnInit {

  constructor(private service: LocationService) {}

   ngOnInit(){
     this.service.getLocation().subscribe(rep => {
        // do something with Rep, Rep will have the data you desire.
     });
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That is indeed the case. I'll add my app.component code

Comment: In my code I set the coords lat and lng variables on the app.component, would you recommend that? And create a new listerener/observable for the map? or just do all the logic in the subscribe of the first instance. seems like messy code, no?

Comment: Could you paste your app.component so I can get a better look.

Comment: I wouldn't say that's messy at all, personally that's how I would do it.  First call a service to get the data then manipulate it within the subscribe section of the call.  Also be sure to unsubscribe from the subscription when you navigate away from the component i.e go to another page.  Otherwise the subscription will stay as subscribed and you'll get memory leaks. You can unsubscribe within the ngOnDestroy lifecycle hook.

Comment: @Notflip just another note as I noticed you said you're learning `Angular2` the `constructor` is only used for `dependency injection` never use the constructor to do heavy lifting.  If you need to make call to the database when the component is requested then set it up within `ngOnInit()`

Comment: And no problem, anytime.